# Tensor product of reflexive sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If E and F are reflexive sheaves of rank one， is their tensor product $E\otimes F$ reflexive？ Thanks！

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you try to compute examples in which $E$ and $F$ are not invertible you will see the answer.

Comment: For some generalizations to the commutative algebra setting, you could also try reading about *symbolic powers* of ideals.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R=k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ be the node and $I=(x,y)$ the maximal ideal.  Then $I$ is reflexive of rank $1$, but the tensor product $I \otimes_{R} I$ is not reflexive.  Indeed, the self-tensor product admits the nonzero torsion section $x \otimes y$.